# Issues with timer python flask

Tags: python, flask, timer

I am trying to display a timer of 5minutes (for example). I am using flask.
I know it could be good to use javascript but I really want to do it with python.

**I have two issues:**

1. First issue: display of the timer - issue to overwrite

I wrote a function for the timer in python which is supposed to display (for example for 50 seconds):
`00:50` then remove `00:50` and have`00:49`, and so on...
But it is displaying:

```
00:50
00:49
00:48
...
```

Here is my code: `screen.py`

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, render_template, render_template_string, stream_with_context
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
timing=0
@app.route('/content', methods=['POST', 'GET']) # render the content a url differnt from index. This will be streamed into the iframe
def content():
    global timing
    timing = 10
    # if request.form.get("submit"):
        # timing = request.form['timing']
        # print(timing)
    def countdown(t):
        
        while t:
            mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
            timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            print(timer, end="\r")
            yield timer
            time.sleep(1)
            t -= 1
        # return timer
        
    return app.response_class(countdown(timing)) #at the moment the time value is hardcoded in the function just for simplicity
    # return render_template('display.html')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    value = "Bonjour"
    title_html = value
    return render_template('display.html', message=title_html) # render a template at the index. The content will be embedded in this template

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

I would like to find the equivalence of `print(timer, end="\r")` for `yield` in order to overwrite the value of timer and not see all the results when it's decreasing. I hope my explanation is clear.

2. Second issue: Input value of the timer

As you can see in my code `screen.py`, my value for `timing` is hardcoded `timing=10`. But I would like to allow the user to enter the value he wants in input like that:

```
if request.form.get("submit"):
    timing = request.form['timing']
    print(timing)
```

You can see these lines in `screen.py`, I commented them to leave `timing=10` because when I write these lines I obtain the following error:

```
Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2021 12:50:26] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Here is the HTML Code linked to my python code `display.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/main.css'/>
    <title>your dish</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{message}}! Here are some informations about your dish:</h1>
    <h2> countdown </h2>
     
    <!-- <p>{{message}}</p> -->
    <form method="POST" action=".">
        <p><input name="timing" value="{{timing}}" placeholder="Enter your time"></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        
    </form>
    <div>
        <iframe frameborder="0" noresize="noresize"
     style='background: transparent; width: 100%; height:100%;' src="{{ url_for('content')}}"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I avoid this error and take into consideration the value entered by the user in the input field of my `display.html`?

Comment: where do you have problem with displaying timer? in console ? Not all consoles may uses `\r`. On page? You would have to use AJAX/JavaScript to get data and replace in HTML. There is no `\r` in HTML.

Comment: error shows that you send `POST` to `/` but you have `methods=["POST", ...]` in `route("/content"...,)` - so you send form to wrong address - it should be `action="/content"` but I don't know it will resolve all problems. I think it would need much more complex code. It may need `JavaScript/AJAX` to start timer and to get current code from server. I don't like also `yield` - it will block timer if you will not get data from function so it may get wrong result.

Comment: frankly, for timer I would use directly `JavaScript` without function `content` and `countdown`

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, it will be best to have client periodically polling the server for a new time value to display. Basically keep refreshing the page. You can avoid that if you use websoket and have server push new time value to the client.

Now your will need a re-design for your back-end. It should just keep track of the starting time, and the duration of the timer that you want, and when the client request a new value of the timer, it subtract the time elapsed (which is calculated by the starting time) from the duration and return the value to the client.

For the 2nd question, your `form` has `action="."` which if I recall correctly, may post to your `index` view instead of your `content` view. To have the form post to your `content` view, you will need `action="/content/"`.

Answer (score 0):

`HTML` doesn't have `\r`.

To replace text in `HTML` you would have to use `JavaScript` with

```
   html_object.innerHTML = text;
```

---

Frankly, for timer I would use directly `JavaScript` like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    value = "Bonjour"
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>    
<body>

Seconds: <input name="timing">
<button onclick="start()">START</button>

<br>
<br>

<div id="result"></div>    

<script>
var timer  = document.getElementsByName("timing")[0];
var result = document.getElementById("result");

var counter = 10;

function update() {
    var mins = Math.floor(counter / 60);
    var secs = counter % 60;
    
    // format text
    if(mins < 10) {
        mins = "0" + mins;
    }
    if(secs < 10) {
        secs = "0" + secs;
    }
    
    var text = mins + ":" + secs;
    
    // replace in HTML
    result.innerHTML = text;
    
    // display in DevTools console
    console.log(text);
    
    if(counter > 0) {
        counter = counter - 1;
        setTimeout(update, 1000);
    }
}

function start() {
    counter = timer.value;
    update()
}    
</script>
</body>
</html>''', title=value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.use_reloader = False
    app.run()
```

`Button` uses `onclick` to execute `JavaScript` function which gets value from `input` and uses `innerHTML` to replace value in `HTML`, and `setTimeout()` to run this function again after `1000ms` (`1s`)

---

As for version with timer in `Flask` I created something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

def countdown(value=10):
    for t in range(value, -1, -1):
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer)
        yield timer
        time.sleep(1)

generator = countdown(10)

@app.route('/content', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def content():
    global generator
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        timing = int(request.json.get('timing'))
        generator = countdown(timing) 
    else:
        try:
            value = next(generator)
        except StopIteration:
            value = "END"
        return value
    
@app.route('/')
def index():
    value = "Bonjour"
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>    
<body>

Seconds: <input name="timing" value="120">
<button onclick="start()">START</button>

<br>
<br>

<div id="result"></div>    

<script>
var timer  = document.getElementsByName("timing")[0];
var result = document.getElementById("result");

var counter = 10;

function update() {
    // GET value from server
    fetch('/content')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        result.innerHTML = text;
        if(text != "END") {
            window.setTimeout(update, 0.1);
        }
    });
}

function start() {
    counter = timer.value;
    // doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
    // POST value from form
    fetch('/content',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({'timing': counter})
          }
    )
    .then(response => update());
}
</script>
</body>
</html>''', title=value) # render a template at the index. The content will be embedded in this template

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.use_reloader = False
    app.run()
```

`Button` starts function which uses `fetch` to `POST` data from `form` and next it runs `update()` which `GET` data from server, and `innerHTML` to update it in `HTML`, and `setTimout` to run it again after short time - now server uses `time` to get data after `1000ms`

To make it simper I send POST with `JSON` data then `form`.

It has some problems. When you click again button then it runs two functions `update()` at the same time and it makes problem on server. It may need to stop `update()`.